# What numbers can be written uniquely as a sum of two squares?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, diophantine-equations

> What numbers can be written uniquely as a sum of two squares?

I was looking at sequence [A125022](https://oeis.org/A125022), which shows the numbers that can be uniquely written as a sum of two squares. Here are a few things that I noticed from the first numbers. We have $1$, $2$, $4$, $8$, $16$, $32$, $64$, $128$. It is then safe to assume that all numbers of the form $2^{s}$ can be written uniquely, where $s \in \mathbb{Z}_{+} \cup \{0\}$. Moreover, primes of the form $4k+1$, for example $5$ and $13$, also appear and, interestingly enough, $5^2$ and $13^{2}$ do not. So, we could also say that $p^{s}$ has a unique representation only when $s = 0$ or $s = 1$. If we analyze $A125022$ a bit more, we notice that $3^{2}$, $7^{2}$, $11^{2}$ are there, so we can conjecture that numbers of the form $q^{2}$ have a unique representation, where $q$ is a prime of the form $4k+3$. Furthermore, for reasons I will say later, I believe $d^{2}$, where $d$ has all of its prime factors of the form $4k+3$, can be uniquely represented as a sum of two squares. It is also possible to see that products of these three cases are in the sequence, for example $2^{2}\cdot 5$, $2 \cdot 5 \cdot 3^{2}$ and $2 \cdot 7^{2}$.

**Conjecture.** A number $n \in \mathbb{Z}_{+}$ can be written uniquely as a sum of two squares if, and only if, $n = 2^{s} d^{2} p^{e_1}$, where $s \in \mathbb{Z}_{+} \cup \{0\}$, $d = 1$ or $d$ has all of its prime divisors of the form $4k+3$, $p$ is a prime of the form $4k+1$ and $e_{1} \in \{0,1\}$.

It is known that a number can be written as a sum of two squares if, and only if, it can be written as $2^{s} t^{2} l$, where $s \in \mathbb{Z}_{+} \cup \{0\}$ and $l$ is a square-free positive integer with all of its prime factors of the form $4k+1$. Thus, we know the number $n$ we conjectured above can in fact be written as a sum of two squares. We only need to understand uniqueness. It is more natural to study these questions with the Gaussian integers, $\mathbb{Z}[i]$. If, for example, we have
$$n = a^{2} + b^{2} = (a+ib)(a-ib) = (\pi_1 \cdots \pi_k) (\overline{\pi_1} \cdots \overline{\pi_k}),$$
where the last expression is the factorization of $n$ in primes of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, then we may get different sum representations of $n$ by exchanging, say, $\pi_j$ for $\overline{\pi_j}$. That is, the product
$$(\pi_1 \cdots \overline{\pi_j} \cdots \pi_n)(\overline{\pi_1} \cdots \pi_j \cdots \overline{\pi_n})$$
should yield a different sum when $\pi_j \neq \overline{\pi_j}$ and at least one of the other primes, say $\pi_i$, also satisfies $\pi_i \neq \overline{\pi_i}$. This does not seem to occur precisely for the numbers conjectured above, which makes me think those are the only numbers that can be uniquely represented.

*Question.* Is my guess correct or am I missing other numbers?

Comment: See the [Jacobi Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_two_squares_theorem#:~:text=The%20number%20of%20representations%20of,congruent%20to%203%20modulo%204.)  Keep in mind that they count solutions using negative integers, but it's easy to adjust for that.

Comment: Correct   when "unique"  refers to $n = a^2 + b^2$ with $a \geq b \geq 0$

Comment: If I understood this theorem correctly, then my guess is wrong, no? If we take for example $2205 = 3^{2} \cdot 7^{2} \cdot  5$, the difference of prime divisors of the form $4k+3$ and $4k+1$ is $4 - 1 = 3$. Jacobi's Theorem says we have to multiply this by $4$, but I assume we have to drop this constant to keep the "actual" unique representations. Then, there are $3$ different ways to write $2205$.

Comment: For $n=2205$ there are $10$ factors of the form $4k+1$ and $8$ factors of the form $4k+3$.  Thus you should expect two solutions in natural numbers, and indeed we get $(21, 42)$ and $(42, 21)$.

Comment: The diophantine $x^2+y^2=z^2+w^2$ has infinitely many solutions.

Comment: Oh, I see. So we count divisors, rather than prime factors. Then $2205$ has a unique representation in the sense that only order changes.

Comment: That is exactly right.

Comment: missing ingredient:  the number  of representations of $n$  as $x^2 + y^2$ is exactly the same as the number of representations   for $2^k n.$  There is a bijection.

Comment: induction on the power of $2:$  if $a \geq b \geq 0$   and $n = a^2 + b^2$  then we have $2n = (a+b)^2 + (a-b)^2$  where we still have $a+b \geq a-b \geq 0.$  The other direction:  suppose $2n =  u^2 + v^2 $   with $u \geq v \geq 0. $   We see that $u \equiv v \pmod 2$. Then $$ \left(\frac{u+v}{2} \right)^2 +    \left(\frac{u-v}{2} \right)^2 = n$$

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3846749/242) for more general results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conjecture is correct.

You are missing no numbers. Any number not on your list would contain a prime power $q^e$ with $q$ of the form $4k+3$, $e$ odd, or a prime power $p^e$ with $p$ of the form $4k+1$ with $e\ge2$, or at least two primes $p_1$, $p_2$ of the form $4k+1$. In the first case $n$ cannot be written as sum of two primes at all, and in the second and third case one obtains readily several different representations of $n$. An essential ingredient to see this is the [Brahmagupta-Fibonacci Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta%E2%80%93Fibonacci_identity)

Each number on your list has actually only one representation. This can be most easily seen by looking at the prime decomposition of $n$ in the ring of Gaussian integers $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, and considering the fact that $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ has unique prime number decomposition up to units. Choosing different units does not result in different representations.
Essentially all different representations arise from combining the factors in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ of the prime decompositions $p_i=(a+bi)(a-bi)$, where $p_i$ is of form $4k+1$, in different ways. For the numbers on your list, there is just one prime $p_i$ of form $4k+1$, hence no different combinations are possible. Your number $d^2$ has only one representation $d^2=d^2+0$, since all prime factors of $d^2$ have form $4k+3$ and therefore are indecomposable ("inert") in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$.